# Unable To Connect To Amazon AWS Instance Using Java SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect to an instance that I've created.

I select the instance, chose "A Java SSH client directly from my browser (Java required)" and enter the path to my key pair file.

However when I click "Launch SSH Client" nothing happens.

There isn't an error message.

Am I misunderstanding what I'm meant to be doing, or is there something going wrong?

[image: Connection settings]

Comment: Just a guess, but try using the full path without the `~`?

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem, but I think you're on the right track. Typing in a completely incorrect path doesn't throw an error either.

Comment: Do you have java installed?

Comment: Installed, and updated.

Comment: have you tried opening your browser's console/debug window?

Comment: Exactly the same issue here. I am on Mac OS and tried with Chrome, Safari and Firefox. In none of them anything happens when clicking the button _Launch SSH Client_ . I also followed [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=145205&start=25&tstart=0), but no luck either. @Batman, did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Solved for me: in my case the problem was that Java was actually not installed, even if I thought it was.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling Java, which fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution ended up being to reinstall Java.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a SAFARI then the problem is actually very simple. For security purposes, SAFARi installs java but does not enable it. Just go to web preferences and Enable JAVA

Comment: for me im not able to get this to work at all, i reinstalled java 8.x, on mac, using safari, or seamonkey (just to get this to work), that Launch SSH Client button isnt triggering anything but java test page shows Java to be working correctly, and in Java  control panel security even have sites in allowed list in security tab.